# Django 1.2 Equivalent of QuerySet.query.as_sql()

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In Django 1.1 I was able to produce the SQL used by a `QuerySet` with this notation:

```
QuerySet.query.as_sql()
```

In Django 1.2, this raises as `AttributeError`.

Anyone know the Django 1.2 equivalent of that method?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Django 1.1, `QuerySet.query` returned a `BaseQuery` object, now it returns a `Query` objects. The query object has a `__str__` method defined that returns the SQL.

Comment: What would it have hurt to have left the old method in for backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 4):

as answered in [In django 1.2.1 how can I get something like the old .as_sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474505/in-django-1-2-1-how-can-i-get-something-like-the-old-as-sql)

it's just:

```
print QuerySet.query
```

Comment: That question was asked after this one, and is in fact a duplicate.