# In django 1.2.1 how can I get something like the old .as_sql?

Tags: python, django

In past versions of django you could construct a queryset and then do .as_sql() on it to find out the final query.

in Django 1.2.1 there is a function ._as_sql() which returns something similar, but not the same.

In past versions:

```
qs=Model.objects.all()
qs.as_sql() ====>

SELECT `model_table.id`, `model_table.name`, `model_table.size` from model_table
```

This shows me a lot of information.

But if I try it in Django 1.2.1

```
from django.db import connections
con=connections['default']

qs=Model.objects.all()
qs._as_sql(con) ====>

SELECT U0.`id` from model_table U0
```

This doesn't show me what fields are actually being selected.  I know this information is available somewhere, because in templates, I can still do:

```
{% for q in sql_queries %}
    {{q.time}} - {{q.sql}}
{% endfor %}
```

which shows me the full version of the query (including the fields selected)

My question is, how can I get this full version within the shell?

Comment: How does `SELECT U0.'id' from model_table U0` not show what fields are being selected? model_table.id is being selected. If the same three fields as your first query were used, it would look like `SELECT U0.'id', U0.'name', U0.'size' from model_table U0`.

Comment: I don't think just selecting id is really enough.  What is actually happening later is that the full information is being selected.

For example, 

    qs=Model.objects.select_related().all()
    qs._as_sql(con) =====>

    SELECT U0.`id` from model_table U0

obviously that is not the intended function of select_related, right?

Comment: The reason I need it is because I am trying to debug a query combining defer / only with annotations, and the only sql I can see django generating is the new 'select id' type of stuff without actually seeing what fields it's trying to select.

Comment: Also see http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/msg/47ab48453367fdd9 that mentions the multi-db case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
qs=Model.objects.all()
qs.query.as_sql()
```

Should do the job [as it is shown here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#automatic-spatial-transformations)

EDIT:

I just try it and get the same error.

```
qs=Model.objects.all()
print qs.query
```

this must give you what you want (:

Comment: what version of django are you in?

in 1.2.1, your code generates
    'Query' object has no attribute 'as_sql'

Comment: sorry for untested code. check my edit.

Comment: if this solution fits your needs, please mark it as answered

Comment: It's `str(qs.query)` to be precise. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900057/django-1-2-equivalent-of-queryset-query-as-sql