# Can Django's ORM output the SQL query it is using?

Tags: django, django-orm

I know that you can output the SQL to see tables that are created. Is it possible for Django to output the sql used for any query like:

```
Protocols.objects.filter(active=False)
```

?  I couldn't find this in the docs, so hopefully someone can point them to me, if in fact Django can do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See Django FAQ: [How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running):

```
>>> from django.db import connection    
>>> connection.queries = []
>>> Protocols.objects.filter(active=False)
>>> print(connection.queries)
```

Comment: Great, don't know how I didn't see that before.

Comment: It's very good but problem is some queries can be erased. You must know where to put the instructions. And if I want to view all queries without the knowledge?

Comment: I mean that sometimes you can see not all SQL instructions if you locate the output only in one place.

Comment: @sergzach: So.. locate the output where you need it?

Comment: Update: Unless you need a full SQL log, then you can either check your database logs, django.db Python log (in DEBUG mode) or use dev server which logs SQL to the console (I don't remember which add-on it is in)

Answer (score 9):

Yes it can. You need to make sure that you have `DEBUG=True` in your settings file

you can see what sql queries have been executed by...

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.queries
```

You obviously need to have executed some queries to see them here.

To see what is executed to deliver a particular QuerySet you can do the following

```
str(MyModel.objects.filter(myvar__gte=15).query)
```

It's documented here
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/

Answer (score 3):

I find the [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) to be invaluable. There's also .as_sql() for in-code display of things (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900057/django-1-2-equivalent-of-queryset-query-as-sql) for a note that's a good line in to it)